# Change color of <div> using onMouseover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, event-handling, onmouseover

Im trying to change the color of the div using omMouse ove Event handler. 
From grey to black
But it doesnt work.

Whats wrong here ?
Also how to use onHover and onMouseout ?

```
<html>

<head>
    <title></title>
    <link type="text/css" href="" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="" ></script>    
    <style>
        div{
            height: 100px;
            width: 100px;
            background-color: grey;
        }
    </style>

</head>

<body>
    <div onMouseover="this.bgColor = '#FFFFFF'">

    </div>
</body>

<script>

</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do by doing this

**By tag**

```
div:hover {
    background-color: red;
}
```

**By div Class**

```
.divclass:hover {
        background-color: red;
    }
```

**By div Id**

```
#divclass:hover {
        background-color: red;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

As the answers show there is a css solution using div:hover.

```
div:hover {
    background: #FFFFFF;
}
```

if you like to have a javascript solution, its here:

```
<div onMouseover="this.style.background = '#FFFFFF'">
//content
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do using CSS

```
div:hover {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/M5K36/)

Using *JavaScript*

```
 <div onMouseOver="this.style.backgroundColor = '#FFFFFF';">khkhkhk</div>
```

[**DEMO using JavaScript**](http://jsfiddle.net/M5K36/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with css:

```
.div{
 backgroundcolor: green;
}
.div:hover{
backgroundcolor: red;
}
```